# replace text with url in twitter feed

Tags: preg-replace, twitter-feed

I have this code:

```
public function linkify($status_text)
    {
      $status_text = preg_replace('/(https?:\/\/\S+)/','<a href="\1">\1</a>', $status_text);
      $status_text = preg_replace('/(^|\s)@(\w+)/','\1<a href="http://twitter.com/\2">@\2</a>',$status_text);
      $status_text = preg_replace('/(^|\s)#(\w+)/','\1#<a href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23\2">\2</a>',$status_text);
      return $status_text;
    }
```

and display feeds from twitter like this

```
        foreach($feed as $feed_item) {
            $html .= '<li>';
            $html .= '' . $this->linkify($feed_item->text) . '';
            $html .= '' . $this->relativedate((strtotime($feed_item->created_at))) . '';
            $html .= '</li>';
        }
        echo $html;
```

result of this code is

```
<li>Twitter Feed Text <a href="http://t.co/TnkNfxCdRu">http://t.co/TnkNfxCdRu</a></li>
```

if anyone can help me, how can I add text inside tag `<a></a>`. for example, to be exactly like this:

```
<li><a href="http://t.co/TnkNfxCdRu">Twitter Feed Text</a></li>
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your first preg_replace to:

```
  $status_text = preg_replace('~(https?://(\S+))~','<a href="$1">$2</a>',$status_text);
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response, but this "Twitter Feed Text" is not fixed, it is different each time

Comment: @user3276648: Ok, but where do you take it from?

Comment: from twitter, default text looks like:

Comment: Twitter Feed Text http://t.co/TnkNfxCdRu, and with preg_replace and where find http replaced with http://t.co/TnkNfxCdRu, i want to add hiperlink to all text.

Comment: thanks but not working, is the same, nothing happens

Comment: @user3276648: Please edit your question and produce some `echo` of `$status_text` before and after the `preg_replace`s.

Comment: like this i put echo before and after preg_replace

Comment: i'm new in this world :)

Comment: @user3276648: No, put `echo $status_text` before all preg_replace and after all perg_replace, before the return and show us what is printed.

Comment: do you want to put echo on my website to show you the result? or here in my question?